# how to find the right integral for comparison test?

Tags: improper-integrals

I should determine whether this is a convergent or divergent integral.
i need to use the comparison test but i don't know where to start.

$$
 \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt{x}}dx
$$

Comment: Maybe show that after a while our function is $\lt \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: As an aside, $\quad\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt[n]x}~dx=n!$

Comment: @ André Nicolas i can't see how can we prove this. can you give me another hint?

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = \sqrt{x}$ then $x = u^2 \to dx = 2udu \to I = \int_{1}^\infty 2ue^{-u}du$. I am sure you can continue with integration by part to finish.

Comment: yes, by integration is easy. i need to prove this, with the comparison test.